# How to install Windows 7 on an iMac without having Windows avialable?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac

All the guides I've read require me to use Windows to make a Windows 7 bootable USB stick. Does anybody know if there is a way of making bootable USB stick without involving any Windows programs?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using boot camp?
http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/

Comment: i dont have windows install dvd, just iso image

Comment: @keymore I'd suggest you burn the ISO to a DVD then. Or go the long way and use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @digitxp i am trying to use rEFIt but i get some error when trying to boot from usb - i assume usb is not bootable because i didn't make it bootable because i don't have windows

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it into a VM?

If not you can take the ISO, install it in a VM temporarily, then follow the guides for Windows and then delete the Windows 7 VM and then install it. I don't think there is a clear cut guide for OS X.

Comment: @cody-harlow the only thing i need windows for is playing bunch of games - that's why VM solution won't help